# rails how to delete cache key using partial match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I am using  redis-rails. For cache key I am using an array:

```
Rails.cache.fetch([self.class.name, :translated_attribute, id, field, I18n.locale]) do
  self.read_attribute field, locale: I18n.locale
end
```

Now I need to remove all the cache with key matches with [self.class.name, :translated_attribute, id]. I know it has `delete_matched` that takes wildcard(*) after key for partial matching.

But I dont know what is the exact key generated. Now I need to know how it makes the key when we use array as key. I mean if I use [:foo, :bar, :dum] as cache key what will be the exact key in cache store?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The default rails cache key format is:  [class]/[id]-[timestamp]

i usually dont use rails default cache key format, instead i create my own keys so it would be easier to manipulate in redis.

```
cache_key = "#{self.class.name}/#{translated_attribute}/#{id}/#{field}/#{I18n.locale}"

Rails.cache.fetch(cache_key) do
  self.read_attribute field, locale: I18n.locale
end

Rails.cache.delete(cache_key)
Rails.cache.delete_matched("#{self.class.name}*#{id}*")
```

Comment: This does not work for memcache as datastore. any other options ?

Comment: Careful about using `delete_matched` in production:

```Performance note: this operation can be dangerous for large production databases, as it uses the Redis “KEYS” command, which is O(N) over the total number of keys in the database. Users of large Redis caches should avoid this method.```

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/redis-activesupport/4.0.0/ActiveSupport%2FCache%2FRedisStore:delete_matched

Comment: @DFish probably the new implementation doesnt have this disadvantage

https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/ef2af628a9ec1cc4e7b6997a021dd3f85cfe4665

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/9a439f633205af0800f34af32f2122150faa2767/activesupport/lib/active_support/cache/redis_cache_store.rb#L187