# How do I cache the result of API call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching

I'm calling an API method from a server:

```
def get_data
  #.........
  get_some_data_from_server
end
```

I want to cache the result of this call, obviously. So I created a field in a table and changed the `get_data` to look like this:

```
  def fetch_data
    key = get_cache_key
    Rails.cache.fetch key, expires_in: 500.minutes do 
      get_some_data_from_server   
    end
  end
```

The result of `get_some_data_from_server` doesn't change frequently, it's pretty much the same all the time. But it may change over time, even **early** when  500 minutes have passed. And thus the user may receive an outdated data from cache.

Is this strategy sensible? What do I do about `get_some_data_from_server` changing over time?

Answer (score 1):

If it has changed, then the key should change. Ideally, you want your key to reflect, in some part, something unique about the data it represents.

In the case of request, for example. If you were making a request that included two dates, to receive data between two points. My key would include those two dates, so everytime I request data from a different range of dates, it wont use the same cache key.

In the case of when the request will always be the same, there should be a way to determine if the api has changed, perhaps through a less expensive api call. If this call says that new data is available, then you should clear the cache at that key and request the new data.

One way to check if data is changed, before you make a request is using ETag's and conditional gets. A detailed description can be found here http://fideloper.com/api-etag-conditional-get

Comment: If it has changed, then the key should change.  - no, why? it's persistent.

Comment: Your key determines whether or not you should make the request or not. Therefore if the request parameters change, your key should change. I have no idea what kind of request get_some_data is doing though.

Comment: how do you know what my key determines on? it doesn't depend on the result of api or anything else. request get_some_data makes an api call. the key looks like "my_api_call_#{current_user.id}".

Comment: What parameters do you use for get_some_data? Do they ever change, or are they static?

Comment: If the API uses etags, you'll want to go that route. If you make a request like curl -i -H "If-None-Match: c0947-b1-4d0258df1f625" example.com/api/todo/4 and don't get a result, then the data hasn't changed, if you get a result, you reset your etag and update the associated data. In this case the API does the caching for you and you can bypass Rails.cache. You just need to store the etag somewhere.

Comment: If I have one etag and want to check if it's changed, I have to make an api call again. And what's the point of etag if I have to make an api call anyway?

Comment: Yes, but if nothing has changed, you get headers back and no content. If something has changed you get headers and the new content.

Comment: and what's the difference?

Answer (score -1):

If the result of `get_some_data_from_server` is changed than the call

```rb
Rails.cache.delete(get_cache_key)
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19603852/1289704